# Etymology of "Factor" in Factor Analysis

Tags: factor-analysis, etymology

What is the etymology of the term "factor" in factor analysis?

Was it chosen to denote mathematical factoring (choosing a common divisor or the product of other values)? Or perhaps a factor in the sense of a driver of events ("the factors underlying economic inequality")? Or something more eldritch?

Comment: Probably the [*Two-Factor theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_theory_of_intelligence) developed by Charles Spearman when studying human ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from [this page](http://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html):

> FACTOR and FACTOR ANALYSIS in PSYCHOMETRICS. The first factor analysis
> was in Charles Spearman’s “General intelligence,” objectively
> determined and measured American Journal of Psychology, 15, (1904),
> 201-293. However the term factor came later; see e.g. Spearman’s “The
> theory of two factors,” Psychological Review, 21, (1914), 101-. The
> term factor analysiscame into circulation in the 1930s. The OED quotes
> from “Multiple Factor Analysis,” Psychological Review, 38, (1931),
> 406-427 by Louis L. Thurstone: “It is the purpose of this paper to
> describe a more generally applicable method of factor analysis which
> has no restrictions as regards group factors and which does not
> restrict the number of general factors that are operative in producing
> the correlations.”

Comment: (+1) Our indirect responses intersected. Here's another reference: [A Beginner’s Guide to Factor Analysis: Focusing on Exploratory Factor Analysis](http://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol09-2/p079/p079.pdf), by Gie Yong and Pearce, Tutorials in Quantitative Methods for Psychology 2013, Vol. 9(2), p. 79-94.